# reading data in C++

Tags: c++, matlab

I am having the matlab code to read binary data:

```
**nfft    = 256; 
navg    = 1024;
nsamps  = navg * nfft;
f_s     = 8e6;
nblocks = floor(10 / (nsamps / f_s));  

for i = 1:nblocks 
    nstart  = 1 + (i - 1) * nsamps;

    fid     = fopen('data.dat');   % binary data and 320 MB

    fseek(fid,4 * nstart,'bof');

    y       = fread(fid,[2,nsamps],'short');

    x       = complex(y(1,:),y(2,:));

end**
```

it will give me complex data with the length up to 8e6.

I am trying to write C++ to do the same function what matab does, but I could not get all the data or they are not the same original.

Can anyone help for ideals?

Here is my C++ code which I am working on.

Thank you so much.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>


 struct myfunc{
    char* name;
 };

int main() {
              FILE* r = fopen("data.bin", "rb");

              fread( w, sizeof(int), 30, r);

              fread(&c, sizeof(myfunc),1,r);

              for(int i=0; i < 30; i++){

                  cout<< i << ".  " << w[i] << endl;
              }
return 0;
```

}

Comment: You never allocated any memory for `name`.

Comment: Where did `w` and `c` come from?

Comment: user4581301: the c I called from the struct myfunc and the w is the vector. so they are will be : int w[40]; myfunc c;

Answer (score 0):

Based on comment

> the c I called from the struct myfunc and the w is the vector. so they are will be : int w[40]; myfunc c;

```
fread(&c, sizeof(myfunc),1,r);
```

will read one pointer's worth of data from file stream `r` into `c`. This will not be particularly useful as whatever address `myfunc.name` pointed at when the file was written will almost certainly be invalid when the file is read back.

Solution: Serialize `myfunc.name` when writing to the file and deserialize it when reading. Insufficient information is in the question to suggest how best to do this. I would store the string Pascal style and prepend the length of `myfunc.name` to make reading it back easier:

```
int len = strlen(myfunc.name);
fwrite(&len, sizeof(len), 1, outfile); // write length
fwrite(myfunc.name, len, 1, outfile); // write string
```

and read it

```
int len;
fread(&len, sizeof(len), 1, infile); // read length
myfunc.name = new char[len+1]; // size string with space for terminator
fwrite(myfunc.name, len, 1, infile); // read string
myfunc.name[len] = '\0'; // terminate string
```

Note the above code completely ignores [endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) and error handling.